# Custom Jenkins metrics for Prometheus

Tags: jenkins, prometheus, grafana, metrics

So I installed the prometheus plugin for jenkins, but now I am not sure how to create custom jenkins metrics that will be exposed in the /prometheus endpoint. What would be the best way to have custom metrics?

Answer (score 0):

I would say your easiest option is to write a plugin.
https://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-custom-plugin

Another approach is to build your own Jenkins fork
https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins
which I probably wouldn't do.